# Unity 2D (C#) - More objects in same position

Tags: c#, object, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I have some 2D objects in same transform position. How can I find out how many objects are in one same position and which objects are they?

EDIT:

Here is my code:
I want save all object on `transform.position - new Vector3(speed, 0, 0)`

```
GameObject go = GetObjectAt(transform.position - new Vector3(speed, 0, 0));

    public GameObject GetObjectAt(Vector3 position)
{
    string pos = position.x + "_" + position.y + "_";
    if (obstacleDictionary.ContainsKey(pos + "BigRed"))
    {
        return obstacleDictionary[pos + "BigRed"];
    }

    else if (obstacleDictionary.ContainsKey(pos + "SmallRed"))
    {
        return obstacleDictionary[pos + "SmallRed"];
    }

    else return null;
}
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Please show us the relevant code parts and avoid "give me the code"-questions.

Comment: It's a universal question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `List<SomeModel>` for keep object and postion.

Add your object to list when the object created
then find same postion object used by `LINQ`

CodeSample

```
   Public class ObjectListener
    {
       public string ObjectName {get; set;}
       public Vector2 ObjectVector {get; set;}
    }



       public class CreateObject : MonoBehaviour 
        {
        List<ObjectListener> _gameObjectListener = new List<ObjectListener>();

        void Update()
        {
         private GameObject _gameObject  ; // you must create _gameObject 
                                           // and set tranform.Postion  maybe you 
                                           //   can use a method returned gameObject 

        Instantiate(_gameObject, _gameObject.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

        _gameObjectListener.Add(new ObjectListener
                                    {
                                      ObjectName =  _gameObject.Name,
                                      ObjectVector  =  _gameObject.transform.postion
                                    });



        }

     }
```

I'm not sure that's the right way, but you can keep all created object name and postion in list object. So you can find how many object are in same object  or not

Comment: I have Dictionary, when i have string key and GameObject value and before every moves i check, if string values (pos.x + "-" + pos.y + "-" + gameobject.tag) == null -> can move, but when i have two object in same pos with different tag, how i can find out? :)

Comment: can u try GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all of the objects have a [`Collider2D`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.html) on them, you just need to call [`Physics2D.BoxCastAll(`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.BoxCastAll.html) and it will return a array of `RaycastHit2D` which you can call `hitItems[i].collider.gameObject` on  to get the object.

```
RaycastHit2D[] hitItems = Physics2D.BoxCastAll(origin, size, angle, direction);
for(int i = 0; i < hitItems.Length; i++)
{
    GameObject hitObject = hitItems[i].collider.gameObject;
    //Do something with the hit object.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is mentioned in the below article

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/638319/getting-a-list-of-colliders-inside-a-trigger.html

1. The basics of the above article

   - Make sure everything has a collider
   - Make sure at least one thing has a trigger
   - User "TriggerList" to get all items with a collider within the trigger.

This article is a second option

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/532746/finding-gameobjects-within-a-radius.html

2. The basics

   - Get a position/transform
   - Get all colliders within a sphere
   - iterate through the list.